# Regexp annoyance

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp that will match a string of numbers exactly 12 times (there may be an additional number at the beginning of the string, which I would then want to discard).

I wrote this regexp to match these numbers when they were all like 123.0123 (\d+.\d+)

```
String str3 = "0.0503    0.0485  0.0481  0.0491  0.0494  0.0489  0.0482  0.0485  0.0479  0.0487  0.0495  0.0487";
```

`Pattern dataLinePattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+\\.\\d+\\s)?((\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*?){12})$");
    Matcher m = dataLinePattern.matcher(str3);

    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }`

expected output is:

0.0503  0.0485  0.0481  0.0491  0.0494  0.0489  0.0482  0.0485  0.0479  0.0487  0.0495  0.0487

However when I try something like

`"^(\d+[\.\d]?\t?)?((\d+[\.\d]?\t*?){12})$"`

or

`"^(\d+(\.\d+)?\t?)?((\d+(\.\d+)?\t*?){12})$"`

to make the decimal places optional, the regexp cuts off the first number and prints just the last 11... What am I doing wrong?

output:

`0.0485   0.0481  0.0491  0.0494  0.0489  0.0482  0.0485  0.0479  0.0487  0.0495  0.0487`
(missing 0.0503)

edit: solved.
 the issue came down to the optional tab delimiter \t*? when that tab is optional for the last 12 numbers the regexp engine would go back and look for a match and find that the last number would match twice: 0. and 0487 (in this example)

rearranging the regexp to put the tab at the beginning of each number rather than "maybe" at the end of each number makes it work.

`Pattern.compile("([0-9.]+\t)?(([0-9.]+)(\t[0-9.]+){11})");`

Comment: It works fine, check http://regex101.com/r/uO1lR6/1

Comment: the code in the first code block works, did you try using the 2 alternate regexps below though? (they didn't paste in correct java format for some reason so you'd have to add backslashes back in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String str3 = "0.0 0.0503    0.0485  0.0481  0.0491  0.0494  0.0489  0.0482  0.0485  0.0479  0.0487  0.0495  0.0487";    

Pattern dataLinePattern = Pattern
        .compile(".*\\s+((\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(\\s+(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)){11})\\s*$");
Matcher m = dataLinePattern.matcher(str3);

if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
}
```

It prints:

```
0.0503 0.0485 0.0481 0.0491 0.0494 0.0489 0.0482 0.0485 0.0479 0.0487 0.0495 0.0487
```

Comment: Don't like those greedy quantifiers, but you guided me to the right path.Pattern dataLinePattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9.]+\\t)?(([0-9.]+)(\\t[0-9.]+){11})");

Comment: Cool. But isn't the first group unnecessary? You can simply put `.*`.

Comment: well you should use .*? actually, but the first group is written explicitly like that to make the regexp run faster. ".*" is greedy and will actually match the entire line and then the regexp engine will backtrack through each character in the whole line trying to match the rest of the expression. That makes the pattern match much more inefficient. The thing is with regexps you should always be as explicit as you possibly can be, for small files you may not see any difference but for large files (think 30GB genome sequences) the difference can become enormous.